# I Have A Problem With Deploying My React App In Github Pages, It Shows Me A Blank Page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, github-pages

I got a problem with deploying my React App to Github Pages. It shows me a blank page.
I added the `Homepage: 'https://Jonathan929-del.github.io/Jonathan-Gym'`
and also the deploy and predeploy codes but it still shows me a blank page, What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that you should set `homepage` , instead of `Homepage` with capital "H".

But in general,
You may follow the steps here:

https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

And this is the official guide:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages

Answer (score 0):

As Alixsep mentioned it could be with the upper case issue. Use

`"homepage": "https://Jonathan929-del.github.io/Jonathan-Gym"`

instead of

`"Homepage": "https://Jonathan929-del.github.io/Jonathan-Gym"` in the `package.json`

If you mean to serve the `index` page of your React app, change it to

`"homepage": "."`

`index.js`:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname)); //here is important thing - no static directory, because all static :)

app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});
```